# Cannot set MS Access options group position to correct value

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have the following, seemingly trivial, VBA code:

```vb
ctrl.Top = offset
```

`ctrl` is an options group control on a form. `offset` is an integer variable. I am using the debugger to step through the code line by line. Using watches, I observe the following values:

Before the line of code:

```
ctrl.Top: 3670
offset: 4170
```

After the line of code:

```
ctrl.Top: 3820
offset: 4170
```

I have tried the following:

- `offset = 6170` --> `ctrl.Top = 3820` (No change)
- `offset = 2170` --> `ctrl.Top = 2170` (Now it's correct)
- `offset = 3821` --> `ctrl.Top = 3820` (No change)
- `ctrl.Top = 3671` before the code --> `ctrl.Top = 3821` after (??)

At first I thought that `ctrl.Top` might have some kind of limit, but the last test suggests otherwise. Is there any mechanism, layout, restriction or *anything* that could cause such a behavior? I honestly don't even know where to start looking.

Comment: Try to remove the _layout_ of the form.

Comment: The layout is already removed (via the "Remove layout" button)

Comment: There are tons of things that may affect the positioning of controls. The main ones are anchoring (does the control move if the form resizes and how) and container size (e.g., controls on the head section of the form can never be positioned to fall below the head section, same goes for tabsets, etc)

Comment: The control is in the main body of the form, not the head or anything. It also doesn't appear to move when resizing the form and the anchor is set to top left. It did change size at some point as I've just noticed, though, so maybe that's related?

Comment: Wait, you're trying to move the control? That's done with `ctrl.Move`.  `ctrl.Top` resizes it.

Comment: Provide your procedure code. @ErikA: Top sets anchor position and does not resize, Width and Height properties do that. Move method has arguments (Left, Top, Width, Height) to set position and size.

Comment: I have no problem setting control Top property to 4170.

Comment: @June7 As a test I have made an `OnClick` event procedure which only contains `Me.Controls("ctrl_name").Top = 4170` and I am still observing the behavior above. `ctrl.Move` also results in the same behavior. So the problem is likely outside of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to eventually figure out what the problem was. As I mentioned in the question, the control is an options group control. Naturally, that group contains buttons to select an option. As it turns out, moving an option group will not move its contents along *and you are not allowed to move the group past it's content*. So any attempt to move the options group past the option buttons resulted in the position getting clipped.